# How do I remove or uninstall Deluge?

Tags: package-management, uninstall, deluge

I upgraded to 12.04 and Deluge broke. I want to remove it and then add it again. How do I remove Deluge?

1. Tried: Searching the Ubuntu Software Centre
   Failed: The button reads "Install" (but it's already installed!)
2. Tried: 
   `sudo apt-get remove --purge deluge`
   Failed: Output read `Removing deluge...` but I can still find it when I search my dash

Comment: How was Deluge installed in the first place? If you used a third party repository, has it been removed? Can you add the output of the removal command to the question.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem uninstalling Deluge. I realized that I had the GTK version installed so merely deleting `deluge` didn't do the trick. I used `sudo apt-get remove --purge deluge-gtk`

Comment: this is the only solution that that worked for me,tnx

Comment: This solution worked for me too , Tried removing deluge , Didn't worked but deluge-gtk worked

Answer (score 5):

If `sudo apt-get remove --purge deluge` succeeded, then the `deluge` package was successfully removed.

If menu items still appear in your dash, it doesn't necessarily mean that the program is still installed, just that links to it remain somewhere.  Possibly, the dash keeps its own cache of what is in your menu, and it takes a little while to realise that a change has been made.

Feel free to go ahead and reinstall deluge now to see if it works.

For future reference, you should look for dotfiles in `~/` or in `~/config` that relate to Deluge.  That is the most likely place it would store data for your account.  Try purging or renaming that instead.  That may solve your original problem with it (rather than re-installing it).

Comment: Package name is `Deluged`, not `Deluge`.

Comment: The main package for Deluge is called `deluge`. `deluged` is a variant that runs as a server daemon.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try complete removal via synaptic package manager?

Install synaptic
`sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Answer (score 0):

As per the OP using `sudo apt-get remove --purge deluge` is the correct way

If you have installed from source files or you need to find leftover Deluge files the Deluge wiki guide has details: [RemovingFromSystem](http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Source#RemovingFromSystem)

---

The most likely reason for it still appearing in Dash is due to a leftover `deluge.desktop` file.

You can use `locate deluge` it will quickly show every file/folder that is named *deluge* and you should be able to determine if the application has actually been removed.

If you installed Deluge from source then you will manually need to remove the files. The main deluge application folder is usually installed in the python *site-packages* or *dist-packages* folder which should be seen in the output from the above command. You will also need to remove the deluge binaries from */usr/local/bin/* or */usr/bin/*.

As neon_overload mentions, if you are having problems with Deluge, backing up and removing your old config may help fix upgrade issues. The default location is: `~/.config/deluge`

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge deluge
```

Apparently you realise when you search for 'Deluge' you will still get it popping up on your screen.

Those are the leftover deluge files - to be completely remove them from your system,

Run:

```
sudo apt autoremove deluge
```

Search and no Deluge will appear..... Magic

Answer (score 0):

The package name is deluged

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge deluged
```

this worked for me

Comment: both `deluge` and `deluged` packages exist

Comment: If you are using deluge  with the  WebUI you just need deluged the other version is used the desktop based