# Deluge refuses to be purged; error persists

Tags: bittorrent, deluge, purge

I'm trying to purge Deluge so I can use KTorrent, because Deluge stopped working. Every time I start a download, it gives me an error message. I tried downloading Ktorrent without purging Deluge to give it a try, but the torrents always go back to Deluge as a default. So I purged it in Terminal. The problem is it still appears. Terminal says I don't have Deluge anymore. The Ubuntu Applications center also says I don't have it installed anymore. But when I search applications, lo and behold, Deluge still sitting there. Any when I download a torrent, it opens right back up in Deluge and continues to get blocked by the same error. I tried changing the default downloader in Chrome, but couldn't figure that out either.

Comment: try sudo aptitude purge packagename and sudo apt-get autoremove                                 see also http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application   and also see this http://askubuntu.com/questions/132967/how-do-i-remove-or-uninstall-deluge

Comment: i dropped into root and purged it there, and it worked

Comment: previously you tried without sudo ?

Comment: I wish i would have written down what I did, because now I forgot. I had been using sudo, but it didn't work because i wasn't in root... I think. I was in username@username-All-series:~$

Comment: i saw a post about something unrelated, that had a command line like sudo -i or something with -i, and when i did that it dropped me to root@username.... and when I purged from there, it worked well.

Comment: found it... sudo -i

Comment: use `sudo apt-get purge deluge*` you should not need to login as root

Comment: to see if an app is installed, run `dpkg -l | grep deluge` for example or `dpkg -l | grep torrent`

Comment: the same problem with deluge came back up. after not using deluge for a while, i tried a download and the first thing i notice is that all previous downloads, which had finished, are not attempting to redownload. then one by one, each gets an error message, until my new download gets the same error message. i purge all the old downloads and try downloading the new one again, but the error mesage just keeps coming back.